# Как быстро отсортировать 3 элемента?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, любой-язык

У меня есть три элемента (массив, не массив - не важно). Как мне их максимально быстро и компактно отсортировать?

Например:

```
a = 7; b = 18; c = -3;
```

Должно превратиться в:

```
a = 18; b = 7; c = -3;
```

Использовать "тяжелую" библиотечную сортировку (тот же QuickSort) для такого тривиального дела, кажется несколько накладно, да и не всегда под рукой есть готовая реализация (или не хочется тянуть зависимости в прогу).

Приведите, пожалуйста, псевдо-код простой и компактной сортировки.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Получить три числа и вывести их по возрастанию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572604/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Сортировка по убыванию 3 целых числа > 0 без if и min/max функций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739079/23044)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Один из самых простых и компактных вариантов - применить пузырьковую сортировку развернув все циклы:

```
if (a > b) then Swap(a, b);
if (b > c) then Swap(b, c);
if (a > b) then Swap(a, b);
```

Answer (score 8):

В дополнение к ответу @Kromster:

Решение с тремя сравнениями — оптимальное. За меньшее количество сравнений отсортировать данные нельзя.

Действительно, у трёх элементов возможно 3! = 6 вариантов перестановки, а за два сравнения у нас есть лишь 4 возможных исхода, следовательно, какие-то случаи будут обрабатываться одинаково.

(Другой вариант того же доказательства: после сравнения первых двух элементов у нас есть три возможных места для третьего, и мы не можем выяснить, какое из них верное, при помощи всего лишь одного дополнительного сравнения.)

Answer (score 0):

Вот прямо тут жмите

выполнить код

и сортируйте себе на здоровье :-)!

```js
function sortNums(a, b, c) {
    a = document.getElementById('a');
    b = document.getElementById('b');
    c = document.getElementById('c');
    var arr = [a.value, b.value, c.value];
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a;
    });
    a.value = arr[0];
    b.value = arr[1];
    c.value = arr[2];
    console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<p>a =<input id="a" type="number"></input>;</p>
<p>b =<input id="b" type="number"></input>;</p>
<p>b =<input id="c" type="number"></input>;</p>
<button onclick="sortNums()">Сортировать</button>
```

Comment: Ну это и есть использование библиотечной сортировки.

Comment: Какой смысл в этом ответе?

Comment: Да, никакого в Вашем понимании. Рассматривайте как воскресное развлечение "чтоб не скучно". Надеюсь, Вас не задело ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Всегда работает:

```
if (a < b) { tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }
if (a < c) { tmp = a; a = c; c = tmp; }
if (b < c) { tmp = b; b = c; c = tmp; }
```

Comment: Извините, а чем ваше решение отличается от принятого ответа?